# Which way is true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$$

How many different subsets that don't involve $4$ and $5$ can be written?

I've solved this question with two part.

Assumed that

$$A = \{1,2,3,6\} $$

By the way

$$2^4 = 16 \tag {1}$$

The other way I've used

$$A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} = 2^6$$
and

$$A = \{1,2,3,6\} = 2^4$$

Then

$$2^6 - 2^4 $$

$$64 - 16 = 48 \tag {2}$$

So, I've got two answer, $48$ and $16$. Which way is true then?

Comment: What would lead you to compute $2^6-2^4$?  (your first method looks fine)

Comment: According to my teacher, the first method isn't correct. He accepted the second method.

Comment: If you wanted to start from the $2^6$ subsets of the big set you would need to subtract all those that contain a $5$ then all those that contain a $6$ then add back all those that contain both.  Good exercise to verify that you get $2^4$ again.

Comment: Are the both true? Why did he accept the second method?

Comment: Clearly not, they give different answers.  Perhaps the question is unclear.  I took it to mean that the subsets must contain neither $5$ not $6$.  Perhaps the teacher meant to exclude only those that contain both.

Comment: So, is the second way acceptable?

Comment: $\binom{6}{2}=15$ and empty set so total of $16$

Comment: Ah, and that explains the second method.  The number of subsets that contain both is the same as the number of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ (just take such a subset and add $5,6$.  So with that interpretation the second method is correct.  But you need to clarify the question.

Comment: @lulu you are great ;) you got what i mean I think. My teacher had accepted the second way for this question. I want to take your thinkings.

Comment: Good!  so both methods are "correct" but they answer different questions.

Comment: @lulu Yes, the problem is there. According to you, which one seems better? If you ask to me, the second way. It must have a solution.

Comment: List: {}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {6}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 6}, {2, 3}, {2, 6}, {3, 6}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 3, 6}, {2, 3, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 6}

Comment: I'm so confused right now.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Isn't it $48$?

Comment: @Maxime I've listed $16$. Are there any others?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire When does my teacher say that the second way is true then?

Comment: @Maxime TheSimpliFire has given a list of all sets which doesn't contain $4$ _or_ $5$ or both. The answer would be $48$ if you were instead looking for the sets which contained neither $4$ _nor_ $5$.

Comment: it says ''and'' so, the both won't be. I'm so confused right now because we've been told that the second way is accepted and wondering why.

Comment: Well if your teacher set the questions and accepted the answer of $48$, then yes, it seems to be that that was the intended question.

Comment: @JohnDoe However, what do you think? Is him right?

Comment: When I first read it, i thought it was $16$. Now I am not sure, the wording is ambiguous to me

Comment: @JohnDoe Right now, I'm so confused.

Comment: Still thinking about why he accepted the second method

Comment: If it involves $4$ but not $5$ is it included or not?  Similarly $5$ but not $4$.      I think this is the difference between the 16 answer and the 48 answer.

Comment: Yes @GEdgar some of the previous comments addressed this - the main concern is what the question wording means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsets of $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

$$\mathscr{P}(A)=\{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{6\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{1,6\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{2,6\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{3,6\},\{4,5\},\{4,6\},\{5,6\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\},\{1,2,6\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,3,5\},\{1,3,6\},\{1,4,5\},\{1,4,6\},\{1,5,6\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,3,5\},\{2,3,6\},\{2,4,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{2,5,6\},\{3,4,5\},\{3,4,6\},\{3,5,6\},\{4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,3,6\},\{1,2,4,5\},\{1,2,4,6\},\{1,2,5,6\},\{1,3,4,5\},\{1,3,4,6\},\{1,3,5,6\},\{1,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4,5\},\{2,3,4,6\},\{2,3,5,6\},\{2,4,5,6\},\{3,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{1,2,3,4,6\},\{1,2,3,5,6\},\{1,2,4,5,6\},\{1,3,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$$

Subsets of $B=\{1,2,3,6\}$

$$\mathscr{P}(B)=\{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{6\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,6\},\{2,3\},\{2,6\},\{3,6\},\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,6\},\{1,3,6\},\{2,3,6\},\{1,2,3,6\}\}$$

$$\mathscr{P}(A)\setminus \mathscr{P}(B)=\{\{4\},\{5\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,5\},\{4,6\},\{5,6\},\{1,2,4\},\{1,2,5\},\{1,3,4\},\{1,3,5\},\{1,4,5\},\{1,4,6\},\{1,5,6\},\{2,3,4\},\{2,3,5\},\{2,4,5\},\{2,4,6\},\{2,5,6\},\{3,4,5\},\{3,4,6\},\{3,5,6\},\{4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{1,2,3,5\},\{1,2,4,5\},\{1,2,4,6\},\{1,2,5,6\},\{1,3,4,5\},\{1,3,4,6\},\{1,3,5,6\},\{1,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4,5\},\{2,3,4,6\},\{2,3,5,6\},\{2,4,5,6\},\{3,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5\},\{1,2,3,4,6\},\{1,2,3,5,6\},\{1,2,4,5,6\},\{1,3,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$$

If we are looking for the subsets that do not contain $4$ or $5$ or both
then the answer is $16$

Hope this helps

Comment: The main issue with the question was the wording - does it mean "doesn't contain 4 or 5" or does it mean "doesn't contain _both_ 4 _and_ 5?

Comment: Why did he accept the second way?

Comment: @Maxime Ask him. It is a linguistic issue. Furthermore my English is pretty poor...